# Difference between Worker#jobs and Sidekiq::Queue#size

Tags: sidekiq

I want to know if a queue is empty.

I see two ways of doing this. Assuming there is a `Worker` job:

- `Worker.jobs.size`
- `Sidekiq::Queue.new('worker_queue').size`

Are there significant differences between the two ways?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A worker is a thread that can execute jobs.  You can have a million jobs enqueued but with `sidekiq -c 5` you'll only have 5 workers processing those jobs.

If you want to know if a queue is empty, use `Sidekiq::Queue.new(name).size == 0`.

Related note: the Sidekiq::Worker module really should have been named Sidekiq::Job.

Comment: At the end I need to use `FooWorker.jobs.empty?` as it works with `Sidekiq::Testing.fake!`. I am a bit confused about your answer though, `#jobs` returns number of jobs in queue right? And assuming I only have one type of job and one queue, `Worker#jobs` and `Sidekiq::Queue#size` should be equal?

Comment: I think there is some confusion around the doc: https://www.rubydoc.info/github/mperham/sidekiq/Sidekiq/Worker#jobs-class_method

It seems `jobs` is from test module, but this appeared in the `Worker` doc.

Comment: Yes, `Worker.jobs` is a `sidekiq/testing` thing.  You should not be using any test APIs in your app code, only test suite.